# Playwright error: browserType.launch: Timeout 180000ms exceeded at Object.playwrightFixtures.browser.scope [as fn]

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

Version:  "@playwright/test": "^1.29.2"

Browser: Microsoft Edge

Has anyone else also faced similar issue before? I'm getting below error,

"browserType.launch: Timeout 180000ms exceeded at Object.playwrightFixtures.browser.scope [as fn]"

I have 3 test modules in my project setup, each module have 8 to 9 e2e test cases.

The Playwright test runner is able to execute the first 2 tests in around 343 seconds (see below pic) however, throwing "browserType.launch: Timeout 180000ms" error on executing 3rd test.

[image]

How can we fix this issue? do we need to manually adjust the timeout in "project\node_modules@playwright\test\lib\index.js:180:51)
at node_modules@playwright\test\lib\fixtures.js:95:81" file?

By the way, I am getting this error when trying to run the tests in serial mode. The tests runs fine if I execute them individually, however I need to execute them all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Under `playwright.config.ts`,
try the `config = { globalTimeout: <your timeout here> }` .

reference:

https://playwright.dev/docs/test-timeouts#global-timeout

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testconfig#test-config-global-timeout